# Does mixing ghee and honey cause clostridium to grow?

Tags: nutrition, surgery

It's said that mixing honey and ghee together can cause Clostridium botulinum infection. How is this possible?

Also a study claims that mixing ghee and honey is useful for open wounds
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3144338/

Article saying mixing both can cause Clostridium botulinum
https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.timesofindia.com/life-style/food-news/can-mixing-ghee-and-honey-turn-poisonous/amp_etphotostory/90415493.cms

Comment: Welcome to the site. What conditions do you think the dressing might be causing that would allow Clostridium to grow?

Comment: "It's said that mixing honey and ghee together can cause Clostridium botulinum infection." -- Who says this?

Answer (score 2):

*[C. botulinum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clostridium_botulinum)* grows best in moderate temperature, low-acidity, low-oxygen conditions and requires a bit of moisture. Poorly canned/"preserved" food that is not sufficiently heated during canning and not sufficiently acidic and then left on the shelf is an ideal environment.

Mixing honey and ghee does not by itself cause this combination of conditions, but a product containing honey and ghee is also not immune to this combination of conditions. It seems like the warning comes from some ayurvedic tradition. This is not an empirical/evidence-based tradition. It sounds to me like a case where the wrong lesson was learned; that is, some food containing honey and ghee was stored improperly, caused illness, and someone decided to blame the honey+ghee combination due to non-scientific beliefs about the "essence"/"temperature" of these ingredients, rather than the storage conditions described above.